# golang extract unique key, value from a key=value pair string using regex

Tags: regex, go

I have the following go string:

```
dbConnStr := "user=someone password=something host=superduperhost sslmode=something"
```

but the k=v pair code may be in any order, for example:

```
dbConnStr := "host=superduperhost user=someone password=something"
```

Notice the difference in the key order and also the missing "sslmode" key in the str.

Also, it is possible that instead of whitespace, the individual k,v pairs may be separated by newline too.

Now I want to extract the unique keys and their corresponding values from the given string, using regexp. If it will help, I can give a list of all the possible keys that may come (username, password, host, sslmode), but I would ideally like a regex solution that works with any list of keys and values.

How to do this ? I understand that it may be possible with regexp.FindStringSubmatch but not able to wrap my head around writing the regexp.

Comment: Things may getting complicated if the value contains `=`. Take a look at the implementation of [`parseOpts`](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/conn.go#L420) function in `lib/pq`. It split key/value pair into a `map[string]string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got answer to this from golang nuts group.

```
    var rex = regexp.MustCompile("(\\w+)=(\\w+)")

    conn := `user=someone password=something host=superduperhost
sslmode=something`
    data := rex.FindAllStringSubmatch(conn, -1)

    res := make(map[string]string)
    for _, kv := range data {
        k := kv[1]
        v := kv[2]
        res[k] = v
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
```

Golang Playground url: https://play.golang.org/p/xSEX1CAcQE

Comment: I have a similar case where the first part of the string remains static and i want to check that part exists. How can i do that? Example string : `ACCESS : user=someone password=something host=superduperhost
sslmode=something`

Comment: A simple strings.HasPrefix won't be sufficient ? If you want that check also to be part of the regex, then I am not that skilled to answer it now. You can ask that as a new question probably.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would look at something like:

((user|password|host)=([\w]+)

giving you key in \1 and value in \2.

Example on playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/6-Ler6-MrY

Comment: Note the character class for \2 on playground needs expanding to allow all the characters you want. I've kept it narrow here intentionally,